# Spring-boot-r2dbc v:2.6.3 and above, not compatible with r2dbc-mssql: v0.9.0-RELEASE

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc

Springboot application is failing with below exception.

*spring-boot-r2dbc-starter:* v2.6.3/2.6.4
*JDK:* 11
*R2driver:* r2dbc-mssql: v0.9.0-RELEASE

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [io.r2dbc.spi.ConnectionFactory]: Factory method 'connectionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: LOCK_WAIT_TIMEOUT
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
... 32 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: LOCK_WAIT_TIMEOUT
at io.r2dbc.mssql.MssqlConnectionFactoryProvider.create(MssqlConnectionFactoryProvider.java:162) ~[r2dbc-mssql-0.9.0.RELEASE.jar:0.9.0.RELEASE]
at io.r2dbc.mssql.MssqlConnectionFactoryProvider.create(MssqlConnectionFactoryProvider.java:48) ~[r2dbc-mssql-0.9.0.RELEASE.jar:0.9.0.RELEASE]
at io.r2dbc.spi.ConnectionFactories.find(ConnectionFactories.java:112) ~[r2dbc-spi-0.8.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
at io.r2dbc.spi.ConnectionFactories.get(ConnectionFactories.java:142) ~[r2dbc-spi-0.8.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
```

**NOTE:** Same application runs fine with r2dbc-mssql: v0.8.8-RELEASE.
**Question:** Is it expected? spring-boot-r2dbc:v2.6.3/2.6.4  is not compatible with r2dbc-mssql: v0.9.0-RELEASE.?

Comment: Did you post in github?

Comment: @K.Nicholas Tried posting, but they redirected me to Stackoverflow. :)

Answer (score 1):

Dependency compatibility mismatch, upgrade r2dbc-spi to 0.9.0.RELEASE, Which is getting added through springboot library as a transitive dependency with the version 0.8.x-RELEASE.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.r2dbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>r2dbc-spi</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

For more details refer [Github Issue](https://github.com/r2dbc/r2dbc-mssql/issues/252) here